# How to Enable a Tiny MCE Plugin?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tinymce

So I've never used tinymce before and I'm working on a project in which it has already been installed. I copied the code from the docs here:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea", // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "advlist"
});
```

But I have no clue where this init function needs to go in order to be called.

Tiny is simply being used to have an email text editor and the line that calls on tinymce (I think) is this:

```
<app-tinymce formControlName='emailBody'></app-tinymce>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also want to reference the TinyMCE Angular docs, you are using the init function that is more for a vanilla HTML/JS approach. Not knowing the exact set up it's hard to say what's going on, but here's the link to the Tiny Angular docs: 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/

And here's the link to the Tiny Angular wrapper on GitHiub:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce

Hopefully that helps, sounds like a tough situation!

Answer (score 0):

After tinymce library and html is loaded (insert this after `<script src={tinymcelib}></script>`) you should call

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "html node to mount editor.
    plugins: "list of plugins to use"
  });
</script>
```

eg. to mount editor to element `<textarea id="editor">` with plugin advlist, you would call it like that:

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor"
    plugins: "advlist"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I am still confused though because the area where the email text editor is utilizes this <app-tinymce></app-tinymce> tag that makes it look like an email text editor. When I change it to <textarea></textarea>, this feature goes away.

Comment: `<app-tinymce></app-tinymce>` is not a valid HTML tag, so the question is what framework are you using? Is it this [angular lib](https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce)?

Comment: It is. I've been handed this project with next to no knowledge of angular or tinymce (or any commenting within the project) so I'm not always certain how things are being made or called, my apologies. I've searched the file structure but this tag only shows up once so it must be an imported function of angular... Yet I can't find anything on google about it.

Comment: No mate, it is part of Angular 2+ api. It a [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). I guess you need to digg into Angular docs :)